# Search item in list view c#

Tags: c#

I try to add item in list view .
But this code like not working at all.
Where did i do wrong ?

```
btn.Click += (senders, eventArgs) =>
{
    foreach (ListViewItem lvis in lvSales.Items)
    {
        if (lvis.SubItems[0].Text == btn.Text)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("!!!!!!!");
        }
        else
        {
            lvis.Text = count.ToString();
            lvis.SubItems.Add(btn.Text);
            lvis.SubItems.Add(btn.Name);
            lvis.SubItems.Add(count.ToString());
            lvis.SubItems.Add(btn.Tag.ToString()); // Email  
            lvSales.Items.Add(lvis);
            count++;
        }
    }
};
```

I wan add item to list view.
If the item already added it will add the quantity
else it will add new .
btw when I clicked the button nothing happen .

Comment: re-instantiate a listviewitem before creating the new listviewitem. Other than that, your code does not really work. You need to increment your qunaitty value when its found, and create new when its not found... Right now, you are incrementing when its not found, and at that, you are not really even incrementing.

Comment: This line 'lvSales.Items.Add(lvis);' within the foreach loop will crash your app, do not edit the collection you're iterating through

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this. It is not completely correct but try and fix minor bugs.

```
var itemFound = false;
foreach (var listViewItem in lvSales.Items)
{
    if (listViewItem.SubItems[0].Text == btn.Text)
    {
        itemFound = true; break;
    }
}

if (!itemFound)
{
    var newlistViewItem = new ListViewItem();
    newlistViewItem.Text = count.ToString();
    newlistViewItem.SubItems.Add(btn.Text);
    newlistViewItem.SubItems.Add(btn.Name);
    newlistViewItem.SubItems.Add(count.ToString());
    newlistViewItem.SubItems.Add(btn.Tag.ToString()); // Email  
    lvSales.Items.Add(lvis);
}
```

Comment: add using System.Linq;

Comment: 'System.Windows.Forms.ListView.ListViewItemCollection' does not contain a definition for 'Where' and no extension method 'Where' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Windows.Forms.ListView.ListViewItemCollection' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: Updated code, Looks like ListViewItemCollection doesn't implements IEnumberable. You can use edited code.

Comment: thanks . the code just got problem. it should "ListViewItem listViewItem in lvSales.Items" instead of var . Thanks alot .!!

Answer (score 1):

you cannot add items to the collection you are iterating through with foreach (lvSales.Items). Consider changing foreach to some other loop like 'for(...'

Answer (score 0):

```
btn.Click += (senders, eventArgs) =>
                {
                    foreach (ListViewItem lvis in lvSales.Items)
                    {
                        if (lvis.SubItems[0].Text == btn.Text)
                        {
                            //get current quantity of listitem, increment it,     
                            //add the new value to this listitem quantity value...
                            //keep track of current index, use that to set the new value...
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            //re instantiate listviewitem, set its values, and add it
                        }
                    }
                };
```

Comment: what do you mean by //re instantiate listviewitem, set its values, and add it ?

Comment: re-initalize / or re-create a listviewitem object. Start fresh with a new one. Set its values, add it.

Comment: look like it doesnt enter the foreach